# Get the size of Document Properties Storage Object

Tags: google-apps-script, documentation, quota

Here is the code snippted that successfully saves 35KB of text.

```
PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("...","...")
```

The defined limit was just 9KB, I wonder what might have happened? Did Google increase the limit? I could store above 9 KB

I see the limit is 9KB
[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#:~:text=Properties%20value%20size](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#:%7E:text=Properties%20value%20size)

What is the actual size allowed limit now?

```js
const characters ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

function generateString(length) {
    let result = ' ';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

    return result;
}

    function myFunction() {
      //throw PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("APP_DATA")
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("APP_DATA",`${generateString(9*1024)+200}`) // added a random string for testing

    }
```

Comment: Without official word from Google we don't really know. But you can try conducting benchmarks of your own to see what the limits are. Try leveraging ByteArrays to generate dummy data of increasing size, convert them to strings, and test if you can store them. It will probably fail at a certain threshold, at which point you'll have a rough estimate of how much can be stored.

Comment: The question is Are you able to retrieve it fully?